# Plesk + Nginx + Prestashop + Muti language get 404 on short url

Tags: nginx, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm looking for a solution with Prestahop 1.7.2 with Nginx server.

I tried dozens of possible solutions, including the official, but all stop working at the time I activate the store with more than one language.

```
2.137.128.33 - - [21/May/2019:11:34:52 +0200] "GET /en/women/2-9-brown-bear-printed-sweater.html HTTP/1.1" 404 6876 "http://tamainut.info/en/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36 OPR/60.0.3255.95"
```

I use a official nginx.conf.dist with adaptations to Plesk interface, because Plesk is a intrusive panel. This use a [nginx.conf](https://dropbox.tamainut.net/owncloud/s/RSTXaSjikdI2YA7)  with call to vhost_nginx.conf (content below) in my test site, [tamainut.info](https://tamainut.info)

```
index index.php;

# Redirect 404 errors to prestashop
error_page 404 /index.php?controller=404;

# Gzip Settings, convert all types.
gzip on;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;

# Can be enhance to 5, but it can slow you server
# gzip_comp_level    5;
# gzip_min_length    256;

gzip_types
    application/atom+xml
    application/javascript
    application/json
    application/ld+json
    application/manifest+json
    application/rss+xml
    application/vnd.geo+json
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject
    application/x-font-ttf
    application/x-web-app-manifest+json
    application/xhtml+xml
    application/xml
    font/opentype
    image/bmp
    image/svg+xml
    image/x-icon
    text/cache-manifest
    text/css
    text/plain
    text/vcard
    text/vnd.rim.location.xloc
    text/vtt
    text/x-component
    text/x-cross-domain-policy;

gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

# HSTS (Force clients to interact with your website using HTTPS only)
# For enhanced security, register your site here: https://hstspreload.org/
# WARNING: Don't use this if your site is not fully on HTTPS!
# add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains" preload; always;

# Cloudflare / Max CDN fix
location ~* \.(eot|otf|ttf|woff(?:2)?)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}

# Do not save logs for these
location = /favicon.ico {
    auth_basic off;
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

location = /robots.txt {
    auth_basic off;
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

# [REQUIRED EDIT IF MULTILANG]
rewrite ^/es$ /es/ redirect;
rewrite ^/es/(.*) /$1;
rewrite ^/en$ /en/ redirect;
rewrite ^/en/(.*) /$1;


# Images
rewrite ^/([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg last;
rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg last;
rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg last;
rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg last;
rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg last;
rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg last;
rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg last;
rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10.jpg last;
rewrite ^/c/([0-9]+)(-[.*_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2$3.jpg last;
rewrite ^/c/([a-zA-Z_-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2.jpg last;

# AlphaImageLoader for IE and fancybox
rewrite ^images_ie/?([^/]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/images/$1.$2 last;

# Web service API
rewrite ^/api/?(.*)$ /webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 last;

# Installation sandbox
rewrite ^(/install(?:-dev)?/sandbox)/(.*) /$1/test.php last;

# [REQUIRED EDIT] Change this block to your admin folder
location /Backoffice/ {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/.*$ /Backoffice/index.php last;
    }
}


# File security
# .htaccess .DS_Store .htpasswd etc
location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
}
# Source code directories
location ~ ^/(app|bin|cache|classes|config|controllers|docs|localization|override|src|tests|tools|translations|travis-scripts|vendor|var)/ {
    deny all;
}
# Prevent exposing other sensitive files
location ~ \.(yml|log|tpl|twig|sass)$ {
    deny all;
}

# Prevent injection of php files
location /upload {
    location ~ \.php$ {
        deny all;
    }
}
location /img {
    location ~ \.php$ {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This works for me:**

```
location ~ (/fr|/en)/index\.php$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

Here's the full configuration file, just in case:

```
server {
        server_name myshop.com www.myshop.com;
        root /var/www/myshop.com/;
        index index.php index.html;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/myshop.com.access_log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/myshop.com.error_log;

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
                auth_basic off;
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        # Deny all attempts to access hidden files such as .htaccess, .htpasswd, .DS_Store (Mac).
        location ~ /\. {
                deny all;
                access_log off;
                log_not_found off;
        }

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_min_length 256;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype image/svg+xml image/x-icon;

        rewrite ^/api/?(.*)$ /webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 last;
        rewrite ^/([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$1$2.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/c/([0-9]+)(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/c/([a-zA-Z-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/c/$1.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/([0-9]+)(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2.jpg last;

        location ~ (/fr|/en)/index\.php$ {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

        location /backoffice/ {
                if (!-e $request_filename) {
                        rewrite ^/.*$ /backoffice/index.php last;
                }
        }

        location ~ .php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(/.*)$;
                #try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_keep_conn on;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;
                fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE open_basedir="/var/www/myshop.com/:/tmp/";
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.myshop.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.myshop.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = myshop.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = www.myshop.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

        listen [::]:80;
        listen 80;
        server_name myshop.com www.myshop.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @bruno-leveque What version of Prestashop?I've tried and not work for me.

Comment: This is for v1.6.1.24. Glad to see your resolved it anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

After see response from Bruno Leveque adapt solution to scenario:

In form text of Plesk for Nginx directives put this:

```
set $admin_dir /Backoffice;
index index.php;

# Redirect 404 errors to prestashop
error_page 404 /index.php?controller=404;

# Gzip Settings, convert all types.
gzip on;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;

# Can be enhance to 5, but it can slow you server
# gzip_comp_level    5;
# gzip_min_length    256;

gzip_types
application/atom+xml
application/javascript
application/json
application/ld+json
application/manifest+json
application/rss+xml
application/vnd.geo+json
application/vnd.ms-fontobject
application/x-font-ttf
application/x-web-app-manifest+json
application/xhtml+xml
application/xml
font/opentype
image/bmp
image/svg+xml
image/x-icon
text/cache-manifest
text/css
text/plain
text/vcard
text/vnd.rim.location.xloc
text/vtt
text/x-component
text/x-cross-domain-policy;

gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

# HSTS (Force clients to interact with your website using HTTPS only)
# For enhanced security, register your site here: https://hstspreload.org/
# WARNING: Don't use this if your site is not fully on HTTPS!
# add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains" preload; always;

# Cloudflare / Max CDN fix
location ~* \.(eot|otf|ttf|woff(?:2)?)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}

# Do not save logs for these
location = /favicon.ico {
    auth_basic off;
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

location = /robots.txt {
    auth_basic off;
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

# [REQUIRED EDIT IF MULTILANG]
rewrite ^/es$ /es/ redirect;
rewrite ^/es/(.*) /$1;
rewrite ^/en$ /en/ redirect;
rewrite ^/en/(.*) /$1;
rewrite ^/zh$ /zh/ redirect;
rewrite ^/zh/(.*) /$1;

# Images
rewrite ^/([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg last;
rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg last;
rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg last;
rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg last;
rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg last;
rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg last;
rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg last;
rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10.jpg last;
rewrite ^/c/([0-9]+)(-[.*_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2$3.jpg last;
rewrite ^/c/([a-zA-Z_-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2.jpg last;

location ~ (/es|/en|/zh)/index\.php$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

# Symfony controllers Specific for 1.7
location ~ /(international|_profiler|module|product|combination|specific-price)/(.*)$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args $admin_dir/index.php$is_args$args;
}

# AlphaImageLoader for IE and fancybox
rewrite ^images_ie/?([^/]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/images/$1.$2 last;

# Web service API
rewrite ^/api/?(.*)$ /webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 last;

# Installation sandbox
rewrite ^(/install(?:-dev)?/sandbox)/(.*) /$1/test.php last;

# [REQUIRED EDIT] Change this block to your admin folder
location /Backoffice/ {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/.*$ /Backoffice/index.php last;
    }
}

# File security
# .htaccess .DS_Store .htpasswd etc
location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
}
# Source code directories
location ~ ^/(app|bin|cache|classes|config|controllers|docs|localization|override|src|tests|tools|translations|travis-scripts|vendor|var)/ {
    deny all;
}
# Prevent exposing other sensitive files
location ~ \.(yml|log|tpl|twig|sass)$ {
    deny all;
}

# Prevent injection of php files
location /upload {
    location ~ \.php$ {
        deny all;
    }
}
location /img {
    location ~ \.php$ {
        deny all;
    }
}

#location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    #   expires 30d;
    #   add_header Cache-Control "public, no-transform";
    #}

    #location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ {
        #   expires 365d;
        #}
        #location ~*  \.(pdf|css|html|js|swf)$ {
            #   expires 2d;
            #}
            location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
                expires 30d;
                add_header Pragma public;
                add_header Cache-Control "public";
            }
```

[Solution explained in Spanish](https://castris.com/como-prestashop-1-7-nginx-multi-idioma/)